# How to check in cn1 (in-app-purchase) if an app was purchased?

Tags: in-app-purchase, codenameone

I have published a free app with ads on Google Play Store.
I consider to implement in-app purchase (non-consumable product, ie. buy-once).
So the app would be either free (restricted functionality) or full version depending whether the user has purchased it. After reading the relevant topics in the cn1 guide and some posts on the web, I still have some questions.

According to cn1-api-javadoc, the method Purchase.wasPurchased() returns true only "if the product was purchased (or has been restored) on the current device." I would like users to be able to use the purchased app on all their devices (including future devices), and on both platforms: Android & IOS. So I need a method like 'wasPurchased()', that returns true on all devices of users who purchased the app. How can this be accomplished? I would like to avoid using my own server for evidence about the purchases and clients.

I also consider, instead of implementing in-app purchase, to publish two separate versions: free version and full version as a 'paid app'. Is it correct that in this case the store (PlayStore or AppStore) will take care about the above problem (users will be able to download and use the full version on all their devices) ?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Isn't a product that can be purchased once "consumable"?

Comment: In the cn1 developer guide it states: "Non-consumable Product - This is a product that the user purchases once to "own". They cannot re-purchase it. One example is a product that upgrades your app to a "Pro" version.".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For both platforms to work you MUST implement this on the server. There's no way around it since both OSs are different. I'm assuming you have a way to identify the user that works in an identical way across platforms. Once you enable that purchased flag in your backend database it should work across platforms regardless of the way in which the purchase was made.

Comment: Thank you for the answer Shai. Can you give me a hint how to identify a user using cn1-api (so that it works across platforms)?
It seems to me much simpler to use the second method of selling the app: two versions (free & full), the full version is a 'paid app' (it can be download only if it is paid beforehand). In that case I don't need to have a server. Is there some drawback of this method that I am not aware of?

Comment: The stores won't let you ID a user or a device. You need a unique ID that would work on both iOS and Android. Neither platform has anything that they support for this due to privacy regulations and policy. Even a device ID is no longer a valid option on both platforms. 
The solution is to collect the phone number or email account and verify it. You then need to store that information somewhere so a different phone can collect that information. You can only do that on a server.